# How to fix error 404 with app.js and app.css in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-6

I am using Laravel 6 and Bootstrap 4.

I made a little app and I was trying to change the background color of the body in the CSS file but I noticed that it didn' work.

So I checked in the tools for the developers and I saw that there are two errors about **app.js** and **css/app.css**

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

I tried adding a **"/"** before the path of the CSS but I failed.

**View:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body style="overflow: hidden; ">
    <div id="app">
        @include('../inc/navbar')
        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        @include('../inc/footer')
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background-color: lightblue !important;
}
```

I would like to see the lightblue body but for some reason it doesn't work. Have you some idea?

Comment: you have a `app.css` file in `yourproject/public/css` and `app.js` file in `yourproject/public/js` ?

Comment: The `app.css` file is in `meetingapp/css/app.css` and the `app.js` is in `meetingapp/resources/js/app.js`... but even adding the folder resources in the asset doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was trying to change the background color of the body in the css file but I noticed that it didn't work.

If this is a fresh install of Laravel, you'll want to run `npm install`. to install all of the front-end assets (css, js etc). If you have *never* made any changes to the css or js, in a terminal you'll need to run this command: `npm run dev` or `npm run watch`. [Here is more documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix) for Laravel Mix.

You won't want to touch the actual `.css` file; it will get overwritten whenever the assets compile. Using the commands above will re-compile all of the `.scss` files into `.css`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I installed npm and I made `npm run dev` ... now the two errors disappear but still the backgroung color of the body remains white. Furthermore now the dropdown menu of the navbar doesn't work... is it maybe a problem with Popper?

Comment: You'll need to change your backround color in `resources/sass/app.scss` (or in whatever `.scss` file you are using). Then re-run `npm run dev` to recompile the css.

If you are using Bootstrap, you may need to pull in each component individually. Or check out the docs on how to pull in the full js library from Bootstrap.

Comment: if by any chance you used symlinks to put index.php in your /var/www/your-site make sure to symlink the css and js folders from public to /var/www/your-site as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to compile the assets. (assume you have already installed npm)

Run

```
npm run prod - if production
```

OR

```
npm run dev  - if development
```

Also you can change the colors in the file `resources/sass/_variables.scss` before compiling the assets.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by running the following commands as explained [here](https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/issues/68#issuecomment-1177078791).

```
composer require laravel/breeze
php artisan breeze:install
npm install && npm run dev
```

Comment: thanks for sharing 
I solved same issue with running those commands

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that the location of `app.js` and `app.css` is incorrect:

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)"

**Solution:**

Make your directory structure is like this for JS:  `/public/js/app.js`

Make your directory structure is like this for CSS: `/public/css/app.css`